# E/AndroidRuntime(6696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.thenewboston.travis"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".startingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

1) this is my xml manifest

```
package com.thenewboston.travis;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle InstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(InstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new       Intent("com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}


}
```

2) this is my splash java activity

```
package com.thenewboston.travis;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class startingPoint extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter += 1;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter -= 1;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
        }
    });
}

}
```

3)and that is my starting point java activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text= "@string/text"
    android:textSize="@string/text_size" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/atext"
    android:textSize="@string/btext_size" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/stext"
    android:textSize="@string/btext_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

4) this is my main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/splash">


</LinearLayout>
```

5)this is my splash xml

```
01-30 17:43:17.396: E/(7511): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
01-30 17:43:17.396: E/(7511): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.travis/com.thenewboston.travis.startingPoint}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:    56)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at com.thenewboston.travis.startingPoint.onCreate(startingPoint.java:19)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     ... 11 more
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     ... 24 more
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:898)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>   (TextView.java:556)
01-30 17:43:22.391: E/AndroidRuntime(7511):     ... 27 more
```

6) This is my log cat

7) This code runs the splash screen but when the 5000ms is done it crashes????

Comment: You should post the full stack trace.

Comment: thanks, yeah new to this, trying to run through tutorials and having some issues haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:898)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>   (TextView.java:556)
```

I don't think a text size can be represented by a string.

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textSize="@string/text_size" />
```

Try hard coding this value for all of your Views:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

If it works, look into [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for the appropriate way to set one text size for every View.

Comment: wow yeah thanks! that worked, not sure why i did that haha. take care buddy

Comment: is there i way i can add to your Rep or does it just do it? i clicked that it was helpful

Comment: No trouble. If you click the checkmark I get +15, when you have enough rep to upvote that gives +10.

Comment: does that take away 15 of my rep or it just helps you?

Comment: You keep your rep, only if you post a bounty ([FAQ#bounty]) will you offer your rep in exchange for an answer.